# Change direction in react js

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, i18next

I use `react-i18next` for change language in react.

I set (en/fa) in i18nextConf.js , likes [this](https://betterprogramming.pub/add-multi-language-support-in-react-js-a771c9ab31c3) article.

I want change direction rtl/ltr when change (fa/en ) in this file.

Comment: https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#dir